# bpf error after upgrade crm dynamics to on prem 9.0.5

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

after successfully upgrade to dynamics from 2016 8.1 to 9.0.5 on prem,

we encountered a problem with business process flow,

as we know each bpf has its own entity in the DB,

we use an OOB bpf in incident entity that called phonetocaseprocess,

the problem is that i saw after the upgrade that the newly table created for

that bpf - is empty :() , so all the current incidents failed on update because

i get an error that said that :  **phonetocaseprocess With Id = 196dc1e2-466f-e911-80e6-
00155dc4022d Does Not Exist.**

when i create a new incident record it works fine and a record is created in

phonetocaseproccess table.

someone encountered that? or have an idea? thank you

**UPDATE**

we were able to resolve this by running the script provided in the above forum before the upgrade run, after this the upgrade was successfully completed.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/232669/business-process-flow-instance-exists-error-after-crm-2016-upgrade/639024

The problem occurred because processes in the source environment did not have a unique name in the database, which resulted in the upgrade not converting the data to the correct table in the DB but to another table in new_bpf_guid format.

hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

That's because your existing records are related to the older process and that the process in the newer version has different GUID. See the snapshot below:

[image]

To correct this, you have to migrate the process entity data with the existing primary keys in the older version.

Comment: This is not something that should have been done automatically by the upgrade?
in my case the newer tables for the bpf created empty with no records at all

Comment: Yes, it should have. But it seems those processes' entity data is not in CRM now. Whatever the reason could be, I believe that migrating that data with the existing primary key should resolve this issue.